# Guardar QR en Google drive

Tags: python, google-drive, qrcode

he generado un código QR de una URL desde colaboratory y no consigo guardar la imagen en google drive, alguna ayuda?. He visto lo relacionado por aqui y nada. Gracias

```html
!pip install qrcode
!pip install pillow
!pip3 install pyqrcode
import pyqrcode
import qrcode
img  =  qrcode . make ( 'https://www.facebook.com/events/1046247752382737/' ) 
img . show ()
```

Comment: Solucionado. Sólo había que conectar el note con drive e indicar ruta:

Comment: ¿Quieres escribir una respuesta indicando los pasos a seguir, por si es útil a alguien? Incluso podrías marcarla como aceptada pasado un tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

adjunto código con las modificaciones que permiten hacerlo.

```html
BASE_FOLDER = '/content/drive/My Drive/P/' #defino la ruta a la carpeta "P" de mi drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/') #monto el disco, te pide token para permisos
!pip install qrcode
!pip install pillow
!pip3 install pyqrcode
import pyqrcode
import qrcode
img  =  qrcode . make ( 'https://www.facebook.com/events/1046247752382737/' ) 
img . show ()
img.save(BASE_FOLDER+'/SwimSilvestre') # Guardo la imagen en la carpeta definida antes
```